# App Crash (android.view.InflateException)

Tags: java, android

My App crashes as i run it on Emulator 
Relevant code is as below :-

```
public class BookingStep4Fragment extends Fragment {
static BookingStep4Fragment instance;
public static BookingStep4Fragment getInstance() {
if (instance == null)
instance = new BookingStep4Fragment();
return instance;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");

    localBroadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext());
    localBroadcastManager.registerReceiver(confirmBookingReceiver,new IntentFilter(Common.KEY_CONFIRM_BOOKING));
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    localBroadcastManager.unregisterReceiver(confirmBookingReceiver);
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_booking_step_four,container,false);
    unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this,itemView);

    return itemView;

}
```

}

Error that is diplayed on my Logcat is

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #87: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:761)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
        at edmt.dev.androidbarberbooking.Fragments.BookingStep4Fragment.onCreateView(BookingStep4Fragment.java:155)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2243)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:654)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:146)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1244)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1092)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1622)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:401)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:687)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2271)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1358)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1607)
2019-06-06 19:25:22.904 3826-3826/edmt.dev.androidbarberbooking E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1246)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6301)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:619)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

As soon as i design the UI in xml file (Layout) which is directly linked with the above code (booking_step_four) it crashes. 
I am a beginner need some help. any help regarding this will be highly appreciated.

XML Code is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorBackground">


    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_dialog"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <TextView
            android:text="Thank you for using Apoint"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_bold"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Booking Information"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_bold"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/ic_event_note_black_244dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_booking_time_text"
                android:text="10h00 at 06/06.2019"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_regular"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/ic_account_box_black_24dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_booking_barber_text"
                android:text="David"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_regular"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


        </LinearLayout>

        <view
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_salon_name"
            android:text="@string/salon_1"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_bold"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/ic_web_black_24dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_salon_website"
                android:text="www.salon1.com"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_regular"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/ic_phone_black_24dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_salon_phone"
                android:text="0135-232398"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_regular"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/ic_access_time_black_24dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_salon_open_hours"
                android:text="9h00 - 19h00"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_regular"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/ic_location_on_black_24dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_salon_address"
                android:text="Address of Salon #1"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_regular"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


        </LinearLayout>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_confirm"
            android:text="BOOK"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@color/colorButton"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_bold"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_above="@+id/txt_skip"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please add your XML code.

Comment: Java and JavaScript are two very different languages - please don't use the JavaScript tag when you really mean Java.

Comment: @Jakob - i have posted the XML code for your reference. please have a look and provide your valuable inputs

Comment: @Zoe- i have rectified my mistake . thanks for pointing it out to me. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your xml code you wrote view instead of View

```
 <view
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"/>
```

change it to

```
 <View
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"/>
```

Clean/Rebuild your code if needed, then re-run your app.